# How to make sequential http api calls in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have multiple calls of api in which on depend on another call. How Can I achieve this using rxjs?

Comment: try this [sample](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.serviceInst.firstAPIMethod()
    .flatMap(firstMethodResult => this.serviceInst.secondAPIMethod(firstMethodResult))
    .flatMap(secondMethodResult => this.serviceInst.thirdAPIMethod(secondMethodResult))
    .subscribe(thirdMethodResult => {
          console.log(thirdMethodResult);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let inSequence = (tasks) => { // tasks being an array of functions returning promises
  return tasks.reduce((p, task) => p.then(task), Promise.resolve());
}

inSequence(tasks).then(() => {
  console.log('all requests done');
});
```